# React-native android build error

Tags: android, react-native

I'm just wondering if someone know what might cause following error?

Didn't have any problems before, but after mate added separated folders for debug and test into `android/src/` it began.

> Error: Failed to crunch file
>   C:\Users...\node_modules\react-native-android-snackbar\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\res\drawable-mdpi\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png
>   into
>   C:\Users...\node_modules\react-native-android-snackbar\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\androidTest\debug\drawable-mdpi\abc_btn_switch_to_on_mtrl_00012.9.png
>   :react-native-android-snackbar:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources FAILED

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the file path is too long. Just add the output path as C:\XX\ on your build gradle and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully Arda's answer will work.You can also try deleting android/app/build folder before recompiling